# Stop iterative function python that keeps iterating

Tags: python, loops, stopiteration

I have a function below, that takes a value as an input, and determines a new_value (the new_value will always be less than the original_value). If the difference between the new_value and the original_value is less than a specified tolerance, the new_value is returned. If the tolerance is greater, the function is called again with the new_value as the argument, to calculate a new_new_value. 
Depending on the original_value entered, sometimes the tolerance condition is never met. 
How can I make the function stop iterating after a certain number of iterations? I have tried to put in count=0, the count+=0 after the else, but that doesn't work as it returns to zero each time the function is called again. Thanks

```
def calc_value(original_value):
   # equations to calculate new_value
   if original_value - new_value < tolerance:
      return new_value
   else calc_value(new_value)
```

Comment: This depends specifically on what you're doing in the part you've commented out.

Comment: @jfaccioni how come? Is there some way that I can count the number of times that the function calc_value is called, and after a certain number of times return a new_value?

Comment: @Anna you sort of need `static vairables`.See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop iterating after you reach a certain iteration depth you will need to pass a counter into the function. This can be done with a `default` argument in the function:

```
def calc_value(original_value, count = 0):
   # equations to calculate new_value
   if original_value - new_value < tolerance:
      return new_value
   else:
      if count > 100:
          return new_value  # Handle reaching limit
      calc_value(new_value, count + 1)
```

Every time you call the function reccursively, add 1 to the count and check if the limit has been reached.

By using a `default` argument, you don't need to bother setting it when you call the function:

```
calc_value(42)
```

---

You could even take this further and add a limit argument to specify the iteration limit:

```
def calc_value(original_value, count = 0, limit = 100):
    # ...
    if count > limit:
        return new_value
    calc_value(new_value, count, limit)
```

Then you can define the arguments either by order, or by specifying the argument:

```
# Default values: count = 0, limit = 100
calc_value(42)

# Will set count to default 0, and limit to 150
calc_value(42, limit=150)

# Will set count to 5, and limit to 200
calc_value(42, 5, 200)

# Will set count to 5, and limit to 150
calc_value(42, limit=150, count=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using recursion for this. Use a `for` loop to iterate a fixed number of times, using the tolerance test to break early where appropriate.

```
def calc_value(original_value):
    old_value = original_value
    for _ in range(10):
        new_value = ...
        if abs(old_value - new_value) < tolerance:
            break
        old_value = new_value
    return new_value
```

Comment: This is an infinate loop, don't forget to `i += 1` in the while loop

Comment: Switched to a `for` loop instead; given the way I structured the loop, I wasn't using doing the tolerance test in the loop condition anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `function attributes`. Something like this.

```
def fun(x):
    if fun.counter<=max_value:
        fun.counter+=1
    else:
        return
    print x
    if x:
        fun(x-1)
fun.counter = 0
max_value = 3
fun(5)
```

Comment: I've never seen these before, so these are the same as static variables in c? Is there a way to initialize them within the function like in C?

Comment: @GTBebbo not exactly same but yes can be used as such